# Django Add PrimaryKeyRelatedField List

Tags: django, rest, primary-key

I have two classes

```
class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    brand = models.TextField()
    percentage = models.IntegerField()

class Drinking(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    drinks = models.ForeignKey(Drink, related_name='drinks',blank = True,null=True)
```

and want to add a list of drinks to the Drinking model via a REST POST.

In the serializer I have the following:

```
class DrinkingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    drinks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False ,queryset=Drink.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Drinking
    fields = ('pk','drinks','amount')

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Drinking.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.amount = validated_data.get('amount', instance.amount)    
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

When I try to POST an Drinking Object:

```
{
    "drinks": [2],
    "amount": 5
}
```

I get the Error, that Drinkings.drinks must be Drink instance. My guess is that I have to change the queryset to only get the primary key of the drinks but I don't know how.

***UPDATE***
I did a small change in the logic, so every Drinking class can only have one Drink and one amount. This works now with the following Serializer:

```
class DrinkingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    drink = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=False, queryset=Drink.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Drink object with id 2 exists?

Also, try making request without brackets: `"drinks": 2` - in my DRF Api nothing else is needed.

Comment: Yup, pk = 2 exists but if I would leave out the brackits it would give me an error that an array of integers was expected

Answer (score 0):

I think the field drinks in your Drinking model should be in the Drink model.

```html
class Drinking(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=False)


class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    brand = models.TextField()
    percentage = models.IntegerField()
    drinks = models.ForeignKey(Drinking, related_name='drinks',blank = True,null=True)
```

Then, using these models your serializer should look like this:

```html
class DrinkingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    drinks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False ,queryset=Drink.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Drinking
    fields = ('pk','drinks','amount')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I POST a pk into your suggested module/serializer, I'll receive the following error: TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0]

Comment: @Stef What do you mean post a pk? Do you mean not a list? Thanks.

Comment: @Stef Using my suggestion models, you don't override the create and update methods.

Comment: yeah sorry, I meant a list of primary keys

Comment: It should work then. No need to override those methods.